# Performance testing of a HTTP Request side process

Tags: database, oracle, apache-kafka, jmeter, performance-testing

Is there a way to test only part of your code with jmeter.

My scenario is as follows: User sends an HTTP request. The body data gets inserted into the table, which is read by another service and put on Kafka topic. I would only like to do the performance testing from the point when data gets inserted into the db and until is put on kafka topic.

A normal JMeter HTTP Request wouldn't work, since the HTTP response won't adhere to the data being processed and put on kafka topic.

Also, I believe, I can't just use the JDBC Request, since when data from the request, that gets inserted into the db produces a cascade of other inserts, and all this data is needed by that other service.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. Use [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to kick off the transaction
2. Use [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) and [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to wait until the message appears in Kafka (see [How to Do Kafka Testing With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/kafka-testing))
3. Put the While Controller under the [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) to measure end-to-end processing time